# Greedy algorithm broken implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to implement a greedy algorithm below, So I'm trying to follow the gist of the algorithm details, but I'm getting an error at my IF statement:  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4 
Does anyone know if the below method is how I should be approaching this?

> 1. Color first vertex with first color.
> 2. Do following for remaining V-1 vertices.
>
>    a) Consider the currently picked vertex and color it with the 
>                   lowest numbered color that has not been used on any previously
>                   colored vertices adjacent to it. If all previously used colors 
>                   appear on vertices adjacent to v, assign a new color to it. */

```
public void greedy(LinkedHashMap<String, Node> nodes) {         
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> colorsUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    nodes.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().currentColor = 1; 
    colorsUsed.add(1);
    for (Map.Entry<String,Node> entry : nodes.entrySet()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.entrySet().size(); i++) {
            if(entry.getValue().edges.get(i).currentColor == 0) {
                //assign a color
                System.out.println(colors.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your nested loop doesn't make much sense and it's the cause of the exception (you stop `i` at the number of nodes instead of the number of edges per node, hence the index `i` is out of the bounds of the collection `entry.getValue().edges`).

You should probably replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.entrySet().size(); i++) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if(entry.getValue().edges.get(i).currentColor == 0) {
```

With something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().edges.size(); i++) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if(entry.getValue().edges.get(i).currentColor == 0) {
```

*(Supposing `Node#edged` implements java.util.List)*

Also, `colors.get(i)` doesn't make much sense either...

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is telling you that your program is trying to get access to a position of your `ArrayList` where it can't access, because the size is smaller than the index. If you want more information about this exception, you should look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

You should check into your code, especially into your loops.